# How to solve this InvalidDatetimeFormat error in Odoo 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-11

I'm getting the error:

> InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: "%Y-%m-%d"
>   LINE 1: ...,12)))  AND  ("sale_order_line"."confirm_date" >= '%Y-%m-%d'...

My code from wizard is:

```
@api.multi
    def export_xls(self):
        context = self._context
        datas = {'ids': context.get('active_ids', [])}
        datas['model'] = 'wizard.stock.history'
        tmp = self.read(['start_date', 'end_date'])
        if len(tmp) > 0:
            datas['form'] = tmp[0]
        for field in datas['form'].keys():
            if isinstance(datas['form'][field], tuple):
                datas['form'][field] = datas['form'][field]
        if context.get('xls_export'):
            return self.env.ref('product_category_report.stock_xlsx').report_action(self, data=datas)
```

And my code from rendering is:

```
sale_obj = self.env['sale.order.line'].search([('order_id.state', 'in', ('sale', 'done')),
                                                       ('product_id', '=', product.id),
                                                       ('order_id.warehouse_id', '=', warehouse),
                                                       ('confirm_date', '>=', start_date),
                                                       ('confirm_date', '<=', end_date)])
```

I was taking stock reports from the odoo v11. But in this scenario, the `error` is happening like this. I don't know why, I have tried in many other ways, still the error is there.

Answer (score 2):

Please convert the start date and end date to datetime if confirm date is datetime field, using below code

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: ValueError: time data 'start_date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: Please provide the format as start_date, if start_date is in '2019/08/08' then give as '%Y/%m/%d'. if start_date as '08/08/2019' then give as '%d/%m/%Y'. I have generally coded, you have to change according to start_date, but please note that  strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") be as this itself.